# How to remove the first characters from strings?

Tags: regex

Before :

```
c3a848415acf99bd656edb67fe6f4473 MD5 : d7Sanne1949
8c20ef279947aa107e6e8043a3cb0975 MD5 : b0angela
1edd31297ccb89b719e998e11b0f14d1 MD5 : 6dviv13
ed3fcef597fd4f33cd2785f31a992bcf MD5 : 9barmagh98
2d078a00ce2cf322948d87be7cbe7979 MD5 : 13tmart123
```

After :

```
d7Sanne1949
b0angela
6dviv13
9barmagh98
13tmart123
```

How to remove c3a848415acf99bd656edb67fe6f4473 MD5 : , 8c20ef279947aa107e6e8043a3cb0975 MD5 , etc ?

Comment: which editor? tool? OS? programming language?

Answer (score 1):

Java examples for:

```
String s = "c3a848415acf99bd656edb67fe6f4473 MD5 : d7Sanne1949";
```

- **without regex**:

  ```
  System.out.println(s.substring(39));
  ```

  or (according to Kent's comment):

  ```
  System.out.println(s.split(" ")[3]);
  ```
- **using regex**:

  ```
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".* MD5 : ", ""));
  ```

  or

  ```
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[0-9|a-f]+ MD5 : ", ""));
  ```

  or

  ```
  System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[0-9|a-f]{32} MD5 : ", ""));
  ```

Comment: Upvoted just for providing the non-regexp solution first. *"Try to solve a trivial problem with regexps and suddenly you have two"*.

Answer (score 0):

Your input looks like it is space delimited, you want the last thing to be output, AND you've got a file with many, many such lines, some which don't have the text you want output. Therefore, using substitution and capturing groups, here's a regex:

```
s/[^ ]+ MD5 : (.+)/\1/
```

(Though, as should be noted, it's a lot simpler to do this with string splitting.)

Here's some Python code that opens the file and runs the regex on each line, printing out the last bit of the line:

```
import re
my_matcher = re.compile(r"[^ ]+ MD5 : (.+)")
def print_extraction(target_string):
    match_result = my_matcher.match(target_string)
    if match_result:
        print match_result.group(1)

target_file = "my_md5s.txt"
with open(target_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print_extraction(line)
```

Comment: A lot of... dashes? Hyphens? Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Alright, I've updated my answer with the assumption that you wanted the lines of text read from a file and the non-MD5 portion of the line printed out.